# How to read httpbody from android webview?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I'm developing app which have payment gateway, I redirect the payment gateway using Webview from app, After successful payment I need to read the response from webview, I done that successfully  in iOS using below.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

      NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Request body %@", responseBody); 
}
```

I want similar like this in android, Is there anyway to read response from Android webview.
I tried with below method but its not works.

```
 @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            WebResourceResponse response = super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);// Always null
            
                try {
                    InputStream strem = response.getData();
                    String body = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(strem), "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println("Boday " + body);
                    strem.close();

            }catch(IOException e){

            }
}
```

WebResourceRequest class did not have anything related to httpbody. WebResourceResponse class always coming null

Comment: Interesting question

Comment: Have you found out a solution to this ?

Comment: No, Its not possible to read.